# AmE vs BrE pronunciation of "piste"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english

According to this extract from Wikipedia, the pronunciation of the term  ***[piste](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piste)*** meaning "*a ski run of compacted snow."*:

> - varies slightly in English, with ***British English using a long "e",*** (e.g. rhymes with "beast"), and ***American pronunciation using a short "i"*** (e.g. rhymes with "list").

Actually, references  such as the  [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/piste)  or the [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/piste)  suggest that the pronunciation is the same in both dialects, that is, with a long "e".

Does the AmE pronunciation of "piste" really differ from the BrE one, or are both versions correct?

Comment: Both [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=piste) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piste). The Wikipedia entry cites *Merriam-Webster* as its source, and the link takes you to an audio file of somebody saying *piste* which doesn't match the actual audio-file you get in *Merriam-Webster*'s online dictionary. So I would be very much inclined to doubt the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: @PeterShor But... the 'pissed' audio-file is marked as 'piste' on the (linked) M-W website... http://visual.merriam-webster.com/sounds/sports-games/combat-sports/fencing/03502.aif It's about _fencing_??

Comment: The [actual website](http://visual.merriam-webster.com/sports-games/combat-sports/fencing/piste.php) this comes from gives a picture of *piste* as it is used in ***fencing***, not ***skiing***.

Comment: @PeterShor Yup. Just saw it. Now onto fencing then...

Comment: @PeterShor - this means that piste has different pronunciations according to the  meaning?

Comment: @JOSH: [This discussion forum](http://www.fencing.net/forums/threads/pronounciation-guide.15073/) seems to indicate that in fencing, both pronunciations are used.

Comment: In the US, not one person in 100 has ever used the word or even heard it used.  Any pronunciation used is either purely a phonetic "guess" or copied from foreign sources.

Comment: @PeterShor British speakers are rather more likely to have heard the term since their skiing is largely done in the Alpine parts of Europe, large areas of which are French speaking. But this has reminded me of the joke about the British skier who thought the notice saying *Suivez la piste* meant "follow that drunk".

Comment: It is a French word and pronounced to rhyme with "beast" so I don't think this is an American vs. British English thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither pronunciation of *piste* (with /ɪ/, like *pissed,* or with /iː/, like *pieced*) seems to be strictly localized to a specific geographical region (which is not surprising, I think, given that it's a rarely-heard word and it's likely a fair amount of people base their pronunciation on its spelling).

Currently, in both regions it seems the /ɪ/ pronunciation is rare and the /iː/ pronunciation is predominant. The comments by [Peter Shor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360597/ame-vs-bre-pronounciation-of-piste#comment838855_360597) indicate that it's possible the /ɪ/ pronunciation is more common in the context of fencing. However, I only saw one person in this [forum thread](https://www.fencing.net/forums/threads/pronounciation-guide.15073/) who mentioned hearing or using this pronunciation, and  [BladorthinTheGrey](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360597/ame-vs-bre-pronounciation-of-piste/367452#comment858002_367452) left a comment here saying "I live in Britain and I am a fencer, I have never heard anyone pronounce it with an /ɪ/". So it seems even in fencing it is quite a minority pronunciation.

The Oxford English Dictionary records the "long e" pronunciation as current for both British and American English, and it also has a note saying the N.E.D.(1907) gave the pronunciation /pɪst/ for the variant of this word spelled *pist.*

Comment: I live in Britain and I am a fencer, I have *never* heard anyone pronounce it with an /ɪ/. Every fencer I've met pronounces it like the original French (/iː/), which is probably related to the French history of the sport (think *En Guarde!*); every non-fencer also uses that. It is, however, easy to see how someone unfamiliar with the term would think of using an /ɪ/.

Comment: More anecdotal evidence - I'm an American who has done some fencing. My experience agrees with that of BladorthinTheGrey.